# How to remove administrator role in settings -> general -> New User Default Role?

Tags: admin, user-registration, user-roles

I don't want to accidentally select Administrator role.

So is there a way to remove it from `Settings -> General -> New User Default Role` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this looks tricky, but I think it's possible.

1. The [`user-new.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/user-new.php) file calls `wp_dropdown_roles()` to output the list of roles.
2. The [`wp_dropdown_roles()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L737) function calls `get_editable_roles()` to get the list of roles to output.
3. The [`get_editable_roles()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/user.php#L182) function has a filter, `editable_roles`.

So, you should be able to add a filter for `editable_roles`, such that, if the current page is `user-new.php`, you unset `administrator` from `$editable_roles`.

#### Edit

> It would be awesome if you can give me the code for my functions.php file.

This is completely untested, but should get you in the right direction. I'm *assuming* that `$editable_roles` is an array of user roles, e.g. `array( 'subscriber', 'author', 'editor', 'administrator' )`, but I've not verified.

```
<?php
function wpse_40897_filter_get_editable_roles_for_new_user( $editable_roles ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( 'user-new.php' == $pagenow ) {
        unset( $editable_roles['administrator'] );
    }
    return $editable_roles;

}
add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'wpse_40897_filter_get_editable_roles_for_new_user' );
?>
```

**Caveat**: This isn't turn-key code, but rather is merely *example* code. If you're not comfortable grokking it to get where you need, then I wouldn't recommend using it for copy-pasta.

Comment: Hello Mr.Bennett, Thanks for the answer. It would be awesome if you can give me the code for my functions.php file. I hope it will definitely useful for others too. Thanks

Comment: See updated answer. Also: **please note the caveat**.